# Read txt file each letter count

Tags: c, mpi

i tried to read a txt file and count all a to z each letter count without considering uppercase and lowercase. i need to ignore other characters and spaces.  but i cannot get correct number count with changig the process count. process need to be in between 1 to 100. with 2 number of process it will show correct count but when i increase the number it shows wrong count.

```
//FILE READING USING MPI FUNCTION
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int size;
    int rank;
    int tag = 0;
    int start;
    int letterCounts[26];
    MPI_Status status;
    int chunksize;
    MPI_Offset file_size;
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(size >= 101){
        printf(" Process failed");  
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
    }
    
    MPI_File file;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "warandpeace.txt", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

    if (file == MPI_FILE_NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
    }
    
        // find the file size
        
        MPI_File_get_size(file, &file_size);
        
        //printf("Process %d:  filesize %d\n", rank,file_size);
        // Allocate a buffer to hold the file contents
        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(file_size * sizeof(char));
if(rank==0){
        // Read the file into the buffer
        MPI_File_read(file, buffer, file_size, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        // Close the file
        //MPI_File_close(&file);
        //free(buffer);
        //deviding the file
        chunksize = file_size/(size - 1);
        //printf("chunksize is %d\n",chunksize);

       int end = chunksize;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            int start = 0;
            MPI_Send(&buffer[start], end - start, MPI_CHAR, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            start = end;
            end += chunksize;
            if (i == size - 2) {
                end = file_size;
            }
           printf("destination rank %d: filesize%d: chunksize = %d\n", i,file_size, chunksize);
        }
        


    }
    else{
        // Receive the file size from process 0
        //long file_size;

        // Allocate memory for the chunks
        //int chunksize = file_size / size;
        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(file_size * sizeof(char));

      
           
        // Receive the chunk of the file and count the letters
        MPI_Recv(buffer, file_size, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        
        int count;
        MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_CHAR, &count);

        printf("count%d: status = %d\n", count, status);
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {

            char c = buffer[j];

            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                letterCounts[c - 'a']++;
            }
            else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                letterCounts[c - 'A']++;
            }
        }

    }

    // Reduce the counts from each process to get the total count
        int totalCounts[26];
        MPI_Reduce(letterCounts, totalCounts, 26, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

           
    if (rank == 0) {
       // Print the total counts
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                printf("%c: %d\n", 'a' + i, totalCounts[i]);
            }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why start at 1 (and not 0) with `for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {`?

Comment: You did not initialise the array `letterCounts`. And then you have `if(rank == 0)` to output the letter counts, but if `rank == 0` you don't accumulate them. I think you need the services of a debugger.

Comment: `buffer` is shadowed.

Comment: compile with `-Wall` and fixes all the warnings. note you do not even need to scatter the file: instead, have each rank read its own chunk, preferably with a collective such as `MPI_File_read_at_all(...)`